# Windows 7 gadget or app that shows stats on multiple network interfaces?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ip, network-interface, desktop-gadget

I am looking for a Windows 7 gadget or app that I can leave on my desktop/sidebar. While there are many gadgets that will display network interface info (such as current IP, gateway, etc), what I really want is to have a way to display all connected network interfaces. So if I am connected to three networks, I'd like to see IP information for all three of them. And, it should be automatic - I don't want to configure the widget each time I change networks.

Does anyone know of a way to make this work, or if someone has already done it?